# How to add multiple hosts to django database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-database, mysql-connector-python

The connection URL to my MySQL server is like so

```
jdbc:mysql://server1:3306,server2:3306,server3:3306/mydb
```

After I parse and extract the hosts and ports, how can I pass it in Django `DATABASES` section below?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'server1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these read replicas? If so you may need to handle load balancing to these outside of Django. If they are for different content see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @TheodoreHowell, these are replicas.

Comment: I believe that is out of the scope of the Django ORM, I would handle load balancing requests elsewhere in the stack unless it is not possible.